# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server Xen server doesn't boot after upgrades

Tags: boot, server, 22.04, xen

Yesterday I did some regular patches on my Xen hypervisor running Ubuntu 22.04 Server. After the apt update / apt upgrade the server didn't boot into Xen anymore. It's stuck trying to mount my root partition device (I think).

Screenshot of error message:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Content of `/boot` :

[image: content of /boot]

When I boot into rescue mode and execute `apt purge xen*` and reboot the server everything works fine again, but I would like to access my VMs again.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, I edited the post.

Comment: Reinstalled my server and Xen, did a reboot, worked. After the reboot the server crashed and now it doesn't boot anymore with the same error message.